# How to reduce the Home link size in my header?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm playing with html and css to make the home link of my header covering only the left half of the header size. Each time I'm resizing the Home Link, it changes my header size. I thought it was because they're in the same div so I put the

```
<img class="header-logo"...</>
```

above the

```
<a class="home-link"...</a>
```

and put it in its own div and gave a brand new id to the logo. Unfortunately that made my header wider which I don't want to. How would you proceed to reduce the homelink size?

I'm using Wordpress and its twentythirteen default theme.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <a class="home-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                <img class="header-logo" src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/resources/logo_big2_v2.png" />
                <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </a>
```

Here is a sample of the related CSS:

```
.site-header {
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    max-width:980px;
    padding:0;
    background-size: 980px auto;
}


.site-header .home-link {
    min-height: 50px; 
}

.header-logo {
    max-width:60%;
    display:block;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

header logo,title and description are all nested inside the .home-link. So changing the homelinks will have impact on the child classes.You might try the code below where you can style individual classes without affecting the other classes.

```
<a class="home-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"></a>
            <img class="header-logo" src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/resources/logo_big2_v2.png" />
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a></h2>
```

Comment: The problems I found with this suggestion is that it makes the home link going under the logo making it not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put so many classes in your html : why not

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <img src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/resources/logo_big2_v2.png" />
    <h1><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
    <h2><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
</a>
```

then

```
/* css */
.site-header {
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
/*    max-width:980px;  not needed : the visitor's choice...*/ 
    padding:0;
    background-size: 980px auto;
}


.site-header > a {
    min-height: 50px; 
    width : 50%; /* site header link will cover only 
             a half of the header, the containing div */
}

.site-header > img {
    max-width:60%;
    display:block;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    position:relative; 
}
```

Comment: The problems I found with your suggestion is that it reduced the home link to the logo only, it disabled the padding-bottom:5px; properties and playing with padding:0; of the .site-header changed the site design as the navbar is part of the header. I set up a testing website here so you can see what I'm talking about: mywptestsite.is-great.org

Comment: OK, You are using a framework.  Good idea, and t-do not touch it.

Comment: Simply, attach property `width:50%` in the css : use `a.home-link{ width:50%; }` in a css (properties are overwritten if css is later in the html.)  I have tested it with my Firefox.

Comment: I used `a.home-link{ width:50%; }` and it didn't work, I tried `.site-header .home-link { width: 50%;}` but it centered my header (logo and site title/tagline). I also tried the `float: left` or `position: absolute; right: 100px` and it messes up everything

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in the end:

```
<a class="home-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
            <img class="header-logo" src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/resources/logo_big2_v2.png" /></a>
            <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
```

and

```
.site-header .home-link {
    min-height: 169px;
    max-width:50%;
    position:static;
left:-250px;
}
```

Now everything seems OK, but not exactly, **the responsiveness is broken and the menu is not resizing at low screen resolution because of the min-height: 169px; CSS property** that I need otherwise the logo is out of the header section. One problem solved, here comes a new one. Edit: I still haven't figured out a solution for this.